# Uninstalling Eclipse Plugins via Commandline/Powershell

Tags: eclipse, plugins, command-line, uninstallation, p2

I am trying to uninstall plugins in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 via powershell through the p2.director application.

Here is what the script I have written entails:

```
./eclipsec.exe `
-clean -purgeHistory `
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director `
-noSplash `
-uninstallIUs `
org.eclipse.rse.cifs.feature.feature.group, `
com.vmware.vide.cimtools.feature.feature.group
```

The script will run for about ~30 seconds and exit without providing any feedback. After re-opening Eclipse the plugins that I have specified have remained installed. If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: you could specify adiitionally the workspace location for the launch and then check inside workspace log.

Comment: The second feature is not part of the argument to `-uninstallIUs` because it is separated by a space.